# PostMan: How can I copy an array/segment from one response to the next request?

Tags: json, xml, api, automation, postman

first post on here! 
I have been playing around with postman automation and managed to copy over ID strings and FAB Id's.
I have seen similar questions asked but didn't quite highlight how I was hoping to do it...

Availability Response;

```
<SessionInfo FABSessionId="FAB123456789"/>
<VehicleSearchResponse Success="true" ModifiedRequest="false">
    <ViewInfo Offset="0" Length="30"/>
    <ResultSetInfo SortCode="cost" SortAscending="true" MaxItems="900" NumItems="30"/>
    <Vehicles>
        <Vehicle StartDate="20181002" EndDate="20181006" PickUpPoint="XXX" DropOffPoint="XXX">
            <Image URL="https://picture.net/example.jpg"/>
            <MoreInfoTexts>
                <MoreInfo Header="..."/>
                <MoreInfo Header="..."/>
                <MoreInfo Header="..."/>
            </MoreInfoTexts>
            <PickUpDepotDetails Telephone="012345 67890">
                <Address Address1="..." CityOrTown="..." Country="..."/>
            </PickUpDepotDetails>
            <DropOffDepotDetails Telephone="012345 67890">
                <Address Address1="..." CityOrTown="..." Country="..."/>
            </DropOffDepotDetails>
        </Vehicle>
........
 </Vehicles>
</VehicleSearchResponse>
```

See above... I want to be able to copy the whole "Vehicle" segment from the availability response to the costing request... It is an array so there is 20 other results below .......

Costing Request:

```
<Itinerary EndDate="20181006" ItineraryId="V!XXX!12345!ABC123!XXX!ABC321!XXX" StartDate="20181002">
<Vehicles>
            {{vehicleSetter}}
</Vehicles>
<OptionalExtras>
```

So the whole Vehicle - /Vehicle segment needs to be copied to {{vehicleSetter}}.

Is there a way to do this using similar (Costing) Pre-RQ scripts to;

```
pm.globals.get("fabSessionSetter");

pm.globals.get("vehicleSetter");
```

and maybe something in (Avail.) Tests script like

```
pm.globals.set("vehicleSetter", jsonObject.FAB_VehicleAvailRS.VehicleSearchResponse.Vehicles.Vehicle[2]);
```

Let me know if you need any more information... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I would ask devs to use json type data for passing to instead of XML. it's much more convenient, I went this way on the begging of the development of a new project, it brought me many benefits. But in case it's possible in your case.
it's not necessary to use global variables.Environment variables are enough.

But try this, I never did it, but perhaps it will help you.
https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio
https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp

Answer (score 0):

I think I had a similar problem to you, having to convert json into xml, either way I had a fantastic response from Sivcan Singh

[Convert XML to JSON for extracting data then convert JSON back to XML in Postman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52317354/convert-xml-to-json-for-extracting-data-then-convert-json-back-to-xml-in-postman)